# WP7 location service dropouts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, location, no-data

I'm working on a WP7 (7.0) GPS tracking app and everythings works great. But one user complains about dropouts of the tracking for 20 seconds up to several minutes.
The strange things:

- the old app version does not have the problem
- no changes in GPS tracking code
- other apps does not have the problem

The app does following location data filtering before processing them:

- timestamp must max. be 30 seconds in the past (prevent using of location data caching)
- geo data must be not unknown

The MovementThreshold of the GeoCoordinateWatcher is set to 5.0 meters and DesiredAccuracy = High.

Any ideas what can go wrong? At the moment I'm clueless. Even if the GPS fix is lost WP7 should do the location stuff with GSM/WLAN so I should receive some (inaccurate) data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be your APP, it could be the location the user is at has very bad satellite communication.

my GPS will stop working in certain areas, randomly.
The user may just be in that situation all the time.

the best bet is to set up a log on a server from the app and update it, watching the signals and errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll go for it and try to figure something out from it.